# Sending mails in background using App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app hosted in GAE, where user can create a Team. On creating new team, a mail will be sent to each of the team members. So, basically send mail function sends mail to many people and it is working fine. I have to run this function in background, so that user can continue to use app without waiting for the send mail function to return.

I read GAE docs, I can use Background Thread https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/background_thread   OR

Task queues for this functionality.

This is the first time I am using task queues or background thread. What do you suggest to use. Is there any other better way to handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

While I am not familiar with background threads, this sounds like a good place to use task queues. They will be easy to debug, as you will be able to browse the tasks in the admin console and run to see that emails are going out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When I send mail, I always use a deferred.defer taskqueue, because of it's ease of use.
To optimize the use of free instances I use this argument :

```
_headers = {'X-AppEngine-FailFast' : 'True'}
```

When I send mail to customers I use Amazon SES, because it is very reliable and because it is easy to monitor bounced messages.